# Are files in iOS automatically sorted by date added?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I was wondering if I added a bunch of files to the Documents directory using FileManager, and at a later time retrieved them, would they already be in "date added" order? I.e., oldest will be first in the array and newest will be last in the array.

I'm asking this because in the simulator if I do `fm.createFile(atPath: ".../Documents/hello1.txt", contents: someData, attributes: nil)` and then do `fm.createFile(atPath: ".../Documents/hello2.txt", contents: someData, attributes: nil)` and retrieve them, they show up in order (hello1 being first then hello2). I was wondering if this behaviour will always be consistent. If it is then I can just do `fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: .../Documents).first!` to get the oldest file in my directory.

Please let me know if this behaviour will be consistent on an *actual* iOS device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no. The order cannot be guaranteed at run time. You'll have to sort the array yourself. I suggest trying something like this instead.

```
    let orderedURLs = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: myDirectoryUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.creationDateKey], options: .skipsHiddenFiles).sorted(by: {
        if let date1 = try? $0.resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey]).creationDate,
           let date2 = try? $1.resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey]).creationDate {
            return date1 < date2
        }
        return false
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

> would they already be in "date added" order?

No. `contentsOfDirectory` is basically just alphabetical if it has any order at all. Sorting by age would be entirely up to you.

It is mere coincidence that in your example age order and returned order are the same.

Comment: From the documentation for [`contentsOfDirectory(atPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1414584-contentsofdirectory): "The order of the files in the returned array is undefined."

Comment: Hmm maybe I should say that.